# Administer randomly nan values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Update :
I woud like randomly administrer NaN values ​​into my dataset for each column taking into account the null values ​​already in my starting data.

At the begening i have to calculate for each columns the NaN values rate contained in my data :

```
{'A': 0.1, 'B': 0.0, 'C': 0.47, 'D': 0.0, 'E': 0.41, 'F': 0.0}
```

Now i woud like to introduce randomly NaN values ​​by column to up :

'nan_percent':

```
{'A': 0.15, 'B': 0.0, 'C': 0.9, 'D': 0.5, 'E': 0.41, 'F': 0.2}
```

Why I do that ? Is to have data that is more looks like the reality of my studie problem.

An i try this code :

```
df = df.mask(np.random.choice([True, False], size=df.shape, p= nan_percent))
```

I have an error :

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'
```

How to administer to each column the right percentage of nan values dandomly via the dict "nan_percent" ?

Answer (score 0):

We can run following code for each column:

```
target = 0.5
col = "Big"
difference = int(target * len(df[col]) - df[col].isnull().sum())
while(difference!=0):
    num = np.random.randint(0, len(col))%len(col)
    if df.loc[num, col] == np.NaN:
        continue
    else:
        df.loc[num, col] = np.NaN
        difference = difference - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
nan_percent_per_column = {'A':0.15, 'B':0.23, 'C':0.10}

for col, p in nan_percent_per_column.items():
    frac = (p - df[col].isna().sum() / len(df))
    n = int(frac * len(df))
    df.loc[df[col].dropna().sample(n).index, col] = np.nan
```

Comment: I have actualy 20 columns in my dataset, if i just want to apply the method on 3 columns, i have this error : ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 20 : given 3

Answer (score 0):

On way to do that: i suppose you want a size of 100

```
nan_percent_per_column = {'A': 0.15, 'B': 0.23, 'C': 0.10}

#create empty DF with columns names for the test
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
for col in df.columns:
    p = nan_percent_per_column[col]
    df[col] = np.random.choice(a=[np.nan, ''], size=100, p=[p, 1 - p])

print(df)
```

if you have already a column X filled you could use  `size=df['X'].shape`

Comment: I get : ValueError: probabilities are not non-negative

Comment: sorry i have no error, your error means p > 1,  you work with number < 1  0.15 for 15% for example?